# function not letting me use #named: string

Tags: ios, swift, function

My problem is that my code will not allow me to use the code below. An error message comes up saying how #named is no longer allowed in swift and I have to double up on named.

```
func addBadGuy(#named:string, speed:Float, ypos:CGFloat){

}
```

However when I do this it says "use of undeclared type 'string'"

```
func addBadGuy(named named:string, speed:Float, ypos:CGFloat){

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type `String` starts with a capital letter, that's the issue

```
func addBadGuy(named named:String, speed:Float, ypos:CGFloat){

}
```